# How to use cell in matlab for this particular code

Tags: matlab, loops, cell

Here is part of my code:

```
for i=1:12
APleft{i}=[-1 0 pointsleftnormalizedplane(1,i) 0;
0 -1 pointsleftnormalizedplane(2,i) 0;
-RE_1(1,1)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(1,i)*RE_1(3,1) -RE_1(1,2)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(1,i)*RE_1(3,2) -RE_1(1,3)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(1,i)*RE_1(3,3) -T_tran1(1)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(1,i)*T_tran1(3);
-RE_1(2,1)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(2,i)*RE_1(3,1) -RE_1(2,2)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(2,i)*RE_1(3,2) -RE_1(2,3)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(2,i)*RE_1(3,3) -T_tran1(2)+pointsrightnormalizedplane(2,i)*T_tran1(3)];

[U{i},S{i},V{i}]=svd(APleft{i});
end
```

Why is always gives error? The problem is in the last line before `end`. I used the cell function in matlab and actually I just want to do the Singular value decomposition for a loop of different matrices but how can I get the decomposition results for each matrix?

Thanks in advance!

The error MATLAB showed is:

> Comma separated list expansion has cell syntax for an array that is not a
>   cell.

```
Error in reconstruction (line 79)
[U{i},S{i},V{i}]=svd(APleft{i});
```

Comment: What's the error?  We can't determine what's wrong unless you tell us what the actual error is.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious.  `U`, `S` and `V` are not cell arrays.  Did you make sure that these were declared as cell arrays before you started this loop?  Try this before your loop.  `U = cell(1,12); S = cell(1,12); V = cell(1,12);`.

Comment: @rayryeng, but if I add, for example, `U=cell(12);` before `[U{i},S{i},V{i}]=svd(APleft{i});` and I run the loop, then I enter, for exmaple, `U{5}`, I only get `ans = []`, not the matrix values. And I also tried your comment, still just an output `[]`.

Comment: Obviously.  You are reinitializing `U` at every iteration, so `U` will be empty except for the very last entry, which is `U{12}`.  Initialize `U` **OUTSIDE** of the `for` loop.

Comment: @rayryeng, finally fixed...thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  I won't even bother with an answer because the issue was quite trivial.  Good luck!